# Display product attribute dropdown box value on product page, with custom placement?

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, custom-attributes, dropdown-attribute, catalog-prodct-view.xml

I'm building a Luma child theme and I want to display my "**brand**" product attribute above the product title on my product page.

I am currently using the following code in my child theme's copy of **catalog_product_view.xml** to also display my "**ingredients**" attribute, this works perfectly because the attribute type is just text:

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">

  <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.ingredients" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" before="-">
      <arguments>
          <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getIngredients</argument>
          <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">ingredients</argument>
          <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">ingredients</argument>
      </arguments>
  </block>

</referenceContainer>
```

My issue is that my Brand attribute type is a dropdown box, if I try to use the code above for dropdown attributes, it just displays a number in the frontend and not my dropdown box value.

How can I properly display the first value in the list? I do not need to display the attribute in a dropdown on the frontend, there is only one value associated with this dropdown, not a list with multiple options.

The fact that the attribute type is a dropdown is only for backend management purposes, so displaying the first value from the list as just text would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the blocks original template (vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml), especially this condition:

```
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
//[...]
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
    $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code))
        ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code)
        : '';
} else {
    $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}
```

So, in your list of arguments add the argument "at_type" and set it to "text" and you should see the attribute option's label

```
<argument name="at_type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
```